# MYSQL Query rows in a database for a phrase and append it if it doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the column maps, and some map names end with the phrase _csgo and others don't. Is it possible to search through that specific column and if the string doesn't have the ending _csgo to add it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an `update` query:

```
update table
    set maps = concat(maps, '_csgo')
    where maps not like '%_csgo';
```

Actually, underscore is a special character in `like`, so you can also do:

```
update table
    set maps = concat(maps, '_csgo')
    where right(maps, 5) <> '_csgo';
```